# How to secure elasticsearch API's

Tags: elasticsearch

I wonder how people normally secure their `elasticsearch` API's, when  being accessed from browser side?

If we access elastic server from server side, even then a simple DELETE request is sufficient to delete a whole index, which might contain priceless information.

I've read that they provide `RBAC` for paid services (which is still in beta),  but what are the best practices being followed to secure the community edition of `elasticsearch`?

Answer (score 3):

To secure elasticsearch without a paid license you can:

**Use third-party plugins**
There are some third-party plugins that can provide some level of security to elasticsearch, Search Guard seems to be the most used to do that.

**Proxy web server**
You can use a web server to provide basic authentication to the API endpoints.

**Firewall rules**
Use firewall rules on your network and elasticsearch server to limit who can access your cluster and from where they can access.

Comment: But Elasticsearch is also my primary database ! On production do we leave our databases without password?   I feel using proxy server is insufficient, the endpoints are still very much vulnerable and it is not very difficult for someone to hack an open ports, e.g. 9200. Thankyou for suggesting search guard.

Comment: what if I set `searchguard.enterprise_modules_enabled: true ?? Will they block it ? ;)

Comment: If elasticsearch is your main database then you should consider buying a subscription. While third-party plugins can offer some level of security, it is not the same as the official one. I do not use Search Guard since the company I work has a subscription from Elastic.

Answer (score 1):

It is necessary to have either a `Gold` or `Platinum` subscription, or a `trial license`.
After that you must enable `xpack` security and config `ssl/tls` on your elasticsearch

for more information check below link

[Elasticsearch Security: Configure TLS/SSL & PKI Authentication](https://www.elastic.co/blog/elasticsearch-security-configure-tls-ssl-pki-authentication)

Answer (score 1):

All the answers here are correct for old versions

From 6.8 the security section become free, just need to follow the instructions [here](https://www.elastic.co/blog/getting-started-with-elasticsearch-security).

Enjoy!